# Using SSLStrip, password is still encrypted

Tags: tls, sslstrip

I did SSLStrip on my network (for educational purpose only!)
And I've got the username and all.

```
system=Test&uid=dixon01&__password=hkulqlyhza&command=login&password=320dd485b1834cf8%7C%40%7C0bf892a5b7dbf901%7C%40%7C5e5f2722f2ed1cc0%7C%28%23%29%7C
```

The ssl works, the connection with the website is http, but the password is still encrypted? Is the password counted as encryption? Or is it just under some encoding?

Comment: What's the password supposed to be?  I see two password fields, I'm guessing the second one is a hash of the password.

Comment: I see that uid=dixon01 and password=hkulqlyhza. It is unclear what the purpose of the second password field is. Perhaps they are passing a salt variable?

Comment: @RoraΖ the password supposed to be b208410480

Comment: @pr user id is fine and correct but the password ??

btw what is salt variable?

Comment: Could be some client-side preprocessing of the form data (e.g. encryption). Inspect the JavaScript code of the page that submits this.

Comment: @JSmyth Well .. so what ssl strip worth ? 
there is a way to find if the javascript encrypt something?

Comment: @Antonio SSLStrip is a MITM tool which strips the victim's hypertext content off HTTPS essentially downgrading HTTPS to HTTP. Just look at the client-side code of the page that sends this form and try to understand how it transforms the form fields.

Comment: @JSmyth I check the website source code
and it said the value goes to __password  , what i saw you before.
but now i entered the same password and the output was different 
now is __password=wcvdghmvac

Comment: My online banking account does the same thing. I always use the same password to log in but if I sniff the wire, it appears different every time.

Comment: @tjt263 so what to do ??

Comment: I wish I knew. Hopefully we find out. What type of website was it in your case? When you checked the source code, did that JavaScript module list an author in the #comments? Maybe we could ask the actual developers for more information.

Comment: What a futile attempt at encryption. Once you do SSLStrip, you can also inject, modify, or remove JavaScript to the page to remove any client side obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

SSLStrip is a transparent proxy that is used to prevent the victim of a MITM attack from uing SSL by clicking on an SSL link. To achieve this SSLStrip replaces all links that start with `https://` with `http://`. The Idea behind this is that most users arent aware of encryption and just use encryption becaue the owner of the webpage links or even redirects them to the secure version of the webpage.

The request you see is clearly not encrypted because you can read it. So this is not a problem of SSLStrip. It is application specific. You can preprocess a password by using javascript. This process can be triggered by clicking the submit button for example. This is done to prevent a sutuation where the pasword travels the wire. It seems like you are in such a situation. Have a look at the webpage with firebug. You can check the button for costum functions triggered when the `click` event is triggered or the input textfield for costum events when `keyup` is triggered for example.

Comment: I do not learn any web programming. i came from networking world. is it necessary to learn web programming language ?

Comment: In forensics it is alway necessary to understand the corpus delicti...

Comment: Alright .. i will learn some javascript.
but before that , and sorry for the newbie question - 
can you explain to me what each parameter does ? 

iptables -t nat  -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

I passed on the info & man page of ip tables , i get it but not clearly. can you help me with that?

Comment: It means that all incoming packets on port 80 are redirected to port 8080 where sslstrip is running

Comment: Each parameter: `-A PREROUTING` means that this rule is aplied before the packet is routed `-p tcp` specifies the protocol,`--desctination-port 80` is the port where the packets come in, `-j REDIRECT` sais that these packets should be redirected and `--to-port 8080` specifies the port where they should be redirected to.

Comment: what about -t nat?

Comment: It describes the table the rule is added to